# Package installs to a different path from existing packages

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 22.04, pkg-config

DPDK installs via `pkg-config` manager. I used these commands to build from source:

```
git clone https://github.com/DPDK/dpdk.git
cd dpdk
meson setup build
cd build
ninja
ninja install
ldconfig
```

https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/build_dpdk.html

However, it installed to `/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig`. In contrast all my other packages are located at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig`.

Because of this `pkg-config --list-all` could not find my DPDK package.

I even set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig` and retried, but it still installed to the same path.

1. Could someone confirm if this is a Ubuntu issue and how should it be installed correctly with the other packages?
2. Is there an easier way of installing DPDK via the Ubuntu package manager? I couldn't find one.

Comment: Setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` should've worked. Can you elaborate what exactly you did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a "DPDK package." You built the software from source, and installed it using a non-Debian tool (ninja). That does not meet the minimum definition of a software package.

You can install software that way all you like, it's not *wrong*. It's just not a *package*.

For a Debian-based system like Ubuntu, your ninja installed DPDK into the correct place.

- `/usr/local` is for non-deb software, including software you built yourself from source.
- `/usr/lib` is for software provided by deb packages (which yours is not)

---

It seems clear that you were misled by the DPDK documentation that building from source was the best way to install.

It's not.

The `dpdk` package has been in the Ubuntu repositories for many years.

Let's see how to find it in a 22.10 system: (hint: it's the very first result)
You will get analagous results for any supported release of Ubuntu.

```
$ apt search dpdk | grep dpdk

dpdk/kinetic 21.11.2-0ubuntu1 amd64
dpdk-dev/kinetic 21.11.2-0ubuntu1 amd64
dpdk-doc/kinetic,kinetic 21.11.2-0ubuntu1 all
dpdk-kmods-dkms/kinetic 0~20220111+git-1ubuntu1 amd64
libdpdk-dev/kinetic 21.11.2-0ubuntu1 amd64
libuhd4.2.0-dpdk/kinetic 4.2.0.1+ds1-1 amd64
libuhd4.2.0-dpdk-tests/kinetic 4.2.0.1+ds1-1 amd64
openvswitch-switch-dpdk/kinetic-updates,kinetic-security 3.0.3-0ubuntu0.22.10.2 amd64
```

Next, let's check the package description to verify that the `dpdk` package is really what we want:

```
$ apt show dpdk
[... snip ...]
Description: Data Plane Development Kit (runtime)
 DPDK is a set of libraries for fast packet processing. Applications run
 in user-space and communicate directly with dedicated network interfaces.
 .
 This package contains the runtime environment to run DPDK applications.
```

Okay, if that matches, then there are two steps to install:

1. (OPTIONAL) Delete your manually-installed duplicate to avoid confusion.
2. `sudo apt install dpdk`

Comment: But surely `pkg-config` should check both if these are well-known paths?

Comment: `pkg-config` is the wrong tool, since you did not install a deb package. Wrong tool = Wrong result.

Comment: But I didn't choose `pkg-config`, that's what the DPDK install script uses?

Comment: Is there a way to install DPDK using an Ubuntu repository? I couldn't see one

Comment: Big edit to answer both questions in your original question, and to show you how to find in in the Ubuntu repositories. Keep in mind that the AskUbuntu format is poorly suited to follow-up questions. It's Question/Answer, not a threaded forum. Try to ask your question...in your Question.

Comment: Thank you so much for that edit. Regarding removing my existing installation, am I dependent on whether DPDK provided an uninstall script?

Comment: That I do not know, as the answer depends upon whatever documentation or scripts the upstream website provides. Those uncertainties around manually compiling and installing and uninstalling are precisely why Debian created standardized *packages* 29 years ago, and we all cheered and never looked back upon the broken chains of our tedium.